# Создание jar файла в gradle/cmd/Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Подскажите пожалуйста, как cоздать в intellij idea , либо в командной строке jar файл. Я знаю,что в II можно сделать это во вкладке artifacts, однако при дальнейшем запуске он попросту не открывается. Возможно, есть какие-то другие утилиты для этого.

Comment: Что зачет не открывается ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сделать как тут
https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/138962/
Если jar файл создался но не запускается(появляется черное окно и сразу пропадает) попробуй создать bat файл в котором прописать 
java -jar Sdvig.jar, где Sdvig название jar файла.